# Method parametrized with type from a range of types in Scala?

Tags: scala

I'd like to define a class inheritance hierarchy so a parametrized method have a parameter type from between my first base class and the current one:

```
class A {
 var x; 
}
class B(parent:A = null) extends A {
 var y;
 protected def method[/* T where, T is subclass of A but super class of type.this */](param:T):Unit = {}
}
class C(parent:B = null) extends B {
 var z
 protected override def method[/* T where, T is subclass of A but super class of type.this */](param:T):Unit = {}
}
```

Is this possible? Is there any reason that I shouldn't try to achieve that (architecture reasons or any others)?

Comment: One small comment, please don't use `null` in Scala if you can help avoid it. That's why they made `Option` types.

Comment: ok thanks, I'll keep it in my mind :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `>: this.type` type bound:

```
class A
class B extends A
class C extends B { def method[T >: this.type <: A](a: T) = a }
class D extends C
```

So you can't call method on `C` with type parameter `D`:

```
scala> new C().method[D](new D)
<console>:12: error: type arguments [D] do not conform to method method's type parameter bounds [T >: C <: A]
              new C().method[D](new D)
                            ^
```

But you can call it with `D` type parameter on `D`:

```
scala> new D().method[D](new D)
res0: D = D@49df83b5
```

Note that any instance of `D` is also an instance of `C`, so `new C().method(new D)` (without type parameter) will be compiled as `new C().method[C](new D)`.

Comment: Could it also be: [A >: T >: this.type] ?

Comment: @VincenzoMaggio: no, the syntax is like this `ParamName (>: UpperBound)? (<: DownBound)?`.

Comment: @senia This is a much better answer than mine!